# Map fails with function name, succeeds with inline function

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

Consider this code:

```
const loadImage = thenify(map.loadImage).bind(map);
const markerNames = ['markers/red-map-marker.png', 'markers/teal-map-marker.png'];

// works
markerNames.map(x => loadImage(x))                      

// works
markerNames.map(function(x) { return loadImage(x) })   

// fails: "TypeError: e is not a function"
markerNames.map(loadImage)
```

I am having trouble understanding why the third form fails. I had thought it was identical in meaning to the second form.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `Array.map()` passes two arguments to the function - the array element, then the array index. The second one is being interpreted as if it's something which should be a function, which it's not.

Comment: it actually passes **three** arguments

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) second argument is index, third argument is original array. Context or `this` is whatever was passed to the second argument of `map()`, in this case, `undefined`.